# Why is codeigniter $this->load->view rendering so slow?

Tags: codeigniter

I have been using codeigniter for quite sometimes and i really love it. But for some reason i am not sure why but rendering a view in 1 of my application takes 18-23 whole seconds. Well i really wonder why as such time is to be taken for rendering the output.

I am sure about this as i measured the time from it reaching the Index Page till the data collection / preparation from the system. All took not less then a second. Just this rendering of the view page screwed up - taking 19 / 23 random seconds.

I really want to understand why as so and will like to get a proper through solution to work around on the same.

As for now i am caching the output and storing it and playing around with it but i too know it is not so full proof solution. There must be a way to analyze as where and why the rendering takes so much time on the server. If anyone knows anything about the same, please please do update / share on the same.

Comment: Have you tried using Codeigniter's profiler for this page? It should show you the timing and work being done to load this page.

Comment: are you loading anything from the database, or running a loop, in that view? The other thing is check firebug for any html/php errors - if you have alot this can slow down the rendering

Comment: CodeIgniter is known for it's speed. You're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using XDebug? There are a lot of online resources for how to use it in profiling your PHP apps, such as [this one](http://erichogue.ca/2011/03/linux/profiling-a-php-application/) by Eric Hogue.

But if you included some sample code of what is happening in your controller and view then perhaps we could offer some specific guidance in this instance.

Comment: I figured out the issue myself. There was some nasty code inserted by one developer causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Removing a call to `$this->carabiner->empty_cache();` speeds up our views quite a bit.